# 404 status instead of returning a token! Why?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt, http-status-code-404

I am writing a Spring MVC application using Hibernate and Spring Boot. I decided to connect Spring Security with JWT. I did everything according to the tutorial, but instead of returning the token as a result, I get a `404` status. Why? And how to fix it?

Configs:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void setJwtTokenProvider(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    // Fields
    //
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    //


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().disable().csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }
}
```

Controller:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController(value = "/auth")
public class AuthenticationController {

    // Fields
    //
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    private final UserService userService;
    //


    // GET-Methods
    //
    //
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> login(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequestDTO requestDto) {
        try {
            String login = requestDto.getLogin();
            authenticationManager
                    .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, requestDto.getPassword()));

            User user = userService.findByLogin(login);

            String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(login, user.getRole());

            Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
            response.put("login", login);
            response.put("token", token);

            return ResponseEntity.ok(response);

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid login or password");
        }
    }
}
```

JwtTokenProvider:

```java
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    // Fields
    //
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Value("${jwt.token.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Value("${jwt.token.expired}")
    private Long validityInMilliSeconds;
    //


    // METHODS
    //
    /**
     * BCrypt
     */
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }


    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        secret = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret.getBytes());
    }

    /**
     * Generate TOKEN
     *
     * @param login
     * @param role
     * @return TOKEN
     */
    public String createToken(String login, Role role) {

        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(login);
        claims.put("roles", getRoleName(role));

        Date now = new Date();
        Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + validityInMilliSeconds);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(validity)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret)
                .compact();
    }


    public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {
        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(getLogin(token));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "", userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }


    public String getLogin(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }


    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token);

            if (claims.getBody().getExpiration().before(new Date())) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new JwtAuthenticationException("JWT token is expired or invalid");
        }
    }


    public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String bearerToken = req.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer_")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }


    private String getRoleName(Role role) {

        String roleName = role.name();

        return roleName;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

P.S. I enter the correct `password` and `login`, according to the entry in the database. If I enter another link, it will return `403`.

(So the problem is that I don't even pass this breakpoint! How can I get through it if I don't get to that place! I get a `404` error)

Comment: I set a breakpoint and started debugging, but it does not work, the console is empty and the application does not stop for debugging, which means that the application does not reach this point

Comment: So the problem is that I don't even pass this breakpoint! How can I get through it if I don't get to that place! I get a 404 error !!

Comment: it means the issue is not related to token at all it is somehow related to resource means the URL which you defined otherwise breakpoint should work

Comment: 404 not found... with /auth1

Comment: May be problem is in cors and csrf?

Comment: As the last resort add another / to your path both in controller and postman so that your path will be like this `/auth/login/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not using tomcat embedded, try to add the project name before your urls. ex :
http://localhost:8080/project-name/auth/login